# jQuery UI Datepicker - Why does the 2nd datepicker disappear onfocus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two `input` elements that function as jQuery UI datepickers. After you make a selection on the first datepicker element it should automatically focus on the second datepicker element and show the calendar, allowing you to easily and quickly make a choice.

For whatever reason the second datepicker/calendar is appearing for a moment and then disappearing. I am not sure why it is disappearing; can anyone offer me an explanation as to why it's disappearing and a possible solution?

Currently utilizing the following libraries: jQuery 1.8.3, jQuery UI 1.9.2

Here's the code I am currently using:

```
<ul class="fields">
    <li><label>Date picker #1</label>
        <input type="text" class="date-picker-1" />
    </li>
    <li><label> Date picker #2</label>
        <input type="text" class="date-picker-2" />
    </li>
</ul>

$('input.date-picker-1').datepicker({
    constrainInput: true,
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    onSelect: function () {
        $(this).closest('.fields')
           .find('.date-picker-2').datepicker('show');
    }
});

$('input.date-picker-2').datepicker({
    onFocus: 'show'
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B78JJ/

If any other information would be helpful please feel free to ask and I'll be happy to help out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems a focus timing issue, the quick workaround is to use a small timeout:

```
$('input.date-picker-1').datepicker({
    constrainInput: true,
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    onSelect: function () {
        var dees = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() { 
           dees.closest('.fields').find('.date-picker-2').datepicker('show');
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

See [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/B78JJ/3/)

Comment: This worked in IE, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari for me. Thanks Nelson. Do you know if this is a common issue with events `onfocus`?

Comment: It's probably some bug/corner case in the jquery-ui datepicker code, it would require to devote some time to debug datepicker to find the exact bug, so if you don't want to spend your time on that then the timeout workaround is the easy way forward.

Comment: It's what I am going to go ahead and use. I'll put in some time trying to find the bug sometime but gotta meet deadlines for now! Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Well, you could just report it in the jqueryui issue tracker, so that maybe other people can take care of it, if you do so, please come back here and paste the link, as I also could give it a go when I have more time.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this:

```
 $(this).closest('.fields').find('.date-picker-2').datepicker('show');
```

You can use:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    $('.date-picker-2').datepicker('show');
}, 1);
```

Comment: we need to open that after some time

Answer (score 0):

Today in august of 2019 we had same issue. You could fix this using method onClose. Another issue appear when options changeMonth or changeYear enabled but it was solved with onChangeMonthYear.

```js
$(function() {
 $from = $("#from");
  $to = $("#to");

 $from.datepicker({
   onClose : function(){
      $to.datepicker('show');
    }
  });
  
  $to.datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month ){
     $to.datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month-1, 1));
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="from">
<input type="text" id="to">
```